# Highlight whitespace for only specified fileds in a JSON file in Visual Studio COde

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have few json files in one of my project folders. I want to configure the settings.json to highlight the whitespace in json files only.

```
{
  "studentname": "ABC DEF",
  "studentage": 19,
  "studentcity": "city name"
}
```

Only "ABC DEF" needs to be highlighted in this json not "city name".

Tried "editor.renderWhitespace": "all", but this highlights all whitespace characters in all the files.

Comment: So, it's not whitespace in JSON files, but whitespace in particular fields? (also, you forgot a colon after "studentcity")

Comment: yes, particular fields in json file

Comment: I solved this with json schema validator

Comment: Could you please post (and accept) an answer explaiing how you did it? That would help otehrs who read this question in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me to implement jsonschema!!!

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json